# Auto cut background image edges

Tags: android, background, size

I would like to improve my androids app design with background image but its resizing/spreading it on screens and make the app uglier as you can imagine,

I googled the issue and the only thing I found is putting many images for smartphone, tablet etc... to get always the best sized image but I m finding a way to put a huge image cut edges when screen is too small without spreading all the image because I don't need to see the whole image

Someone know is it possible and how?

Comment: not many apps use a background images. I didnt see any app that uses a background image. Instead they use some small 40x40 image and spread it in the whole background by repeating it. Maybe this is what you also want to do.

Comment: try using 9 patch images, it will solve your problem. look into [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:
create a new xml in res/drawable

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/mybackgroundimage"
android:gravity="center" />
```